# Options when looking at a limit

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am always confused with these type of terms. Consider the following definition of convergence of sequences and the example of how sometimes is used. This proof appears in [Stromberg.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1470425440)

> **Definition:** A sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subset\mathbb{C}$ is said to converge if there exists $x\in\mathbb{C}$ such that to each $\epsilon >0$ corresponds $n_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $$|x-x_n|<\epsilon$$ for all $n\geq n_\epsilon$.
>
> **Theorem:** Let $(\alpha_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ and $(\beta_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ be sequences in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\alpha, \beta \in\mathbb{C}$. If $\alpha_n \rightarrow \alpha$, then $$\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_k \rightarrow \alpha.$$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Choose $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|\alpha - \alpha_k|<\epsilon/2$ for all $k>n_0$. Next choose $n_1>n_0$ such that $\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n_0}<\epsilon/2$ for all $n>n_1$. Then, $n> n_1$ implies

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|\alpha - \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_k \right| &= \left|\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n (\alpha - \alpha_k)  \right|\\
&\leq \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n_0}|\alpha - \alpha_k| + \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=n_0 +1}^n |\alpha - \alpha_k|\\
&<\frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{n-n_0}{n+1}\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon,
\end{split}
\end{equation}

and so it is proven the statement.

Why the author from the outset chooses $k>n_0$ and does not stick to $k\geq n_0$? Is it because of how he separates the sums? Also, is it really necessary to request $n_1>n_0$? Is it not more simply to request $ n\geq \max\lbrace n_0,n_1\rbrace$?

Comment: The definition of convergence needs a tail condition. It matters not if the inequality is strict. One can be safe and use the maximum condition.

Comment: But when will you say it is more convenient to chose $k>n_0$ over $k\geq n_0$? What I can't still understand is why there is such ambiguity.

Comment: There's no matter of convenience. Remember the definition for convergence says that $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$ when $n \leq N$, but we could just as well say $n > N$. It doesn't matter. So long as the difference between the terms and the limit get small eventually, the definition holds.